# How to get a 2d int array from a char*?

Tags: c++, integer

I want to pass a 2d int array into a main function.
Since the main function signature is like this
    `int main(int argc, char*argv[]`
How can I get the 2d array into a `int[][]` in my code?

Command line:
    `myprogram {{2,3},{5,6},{4,5},{6,8},{2,5}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This: `{{2,3},{5,6},{4,5},{6,8},{2,5}}` will end up as a string in your program. You will need to break it up into pieces yourself to turn it into an array of arrays.

Comment: So I have to manually parse this string and get the values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @cppcoder Yes. As a side note, if you change the format to [[2,3],...] you can probably find existing code that will do this for you. Like a json parser for C++.

Comment: @cppcoder - There is nothing in the standard library for parsing command lines, so unless you can use some other library, like boost::option, you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, and setup proper logic to handle the commas and braces.  Not too difficult, but there are better ways of getting data (xml, file IO, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` function takes either nothing or command-line arguments as `char *`s - you can't just give it whatever you please! You would have to parse the `char *` to get the data you need.

Do you have to enter information in that fashion, though? If it were entered like this (just through `cin`, not command-line arguments:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

You could assign it to an `int a[][]` using something like this:

```
int main() 
{
    const int X=3, Y=3;
    int a[X][Y];
    string currentLine;

    for(int i = 0; i != X; ++i) {
        getline(cin, currentLine);
        istringstream currentInput(currentLine);
        for(int j = 0; j != Y; ++j)
            currentInput >> a[i][j];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the command line input that you give to the program. That might be slightly involved.

What you can do is--since you know that that array is gonna be a 2D array. 
Pass the command line input like this:

myprogram < number of rows(r) > < number of columns(c) > n_1 n_2 n_3 .... n_(r*c)

where `n`s are the elements of your array in 'row-major' fashion.

In this way you code to read the command line input will be much simpler.

Otherwise if you want to retain the format of input. You have to build a 'small' parser to read those input. Basically you have 5 'kinds' of characters that you need to deal with:

1. right brace '} '
2. left brace '{'
3. digits[0-9]
4. comma ','
5. space ' '

Handling space will be little bit tricky because with each `space` in the command line input `argc` increments by one.

**EDIT:** 
You may follow upon these lines. 
**NB:** This code may have errors and some logic also needs to be checked, but this can be a starting point for you to start parsing the command line input in the format that you have given.

```
int main()
{
int count = 1;
std::vector<vector<int>> arr2d;
std::vector<int> arr1d;
std::string buf;
while(count<argc) {
  //accumulate what all you get from command line into string
  buf += argv[count];
  count++;
}
std::string curr_num;
int num_elements;
int i = 0;
int lparen=0,rparen=0,nrows=0;
char c;
while(i<buf.length()){
  c = buf[i];
  switch(c) {
  case '{':
    lparen++;
    break;
  case '}':
    rparen++;
    nrows++;
    arr2d.push_back(arr1d);
    arr1d.clear();
    break;
  case ' ':
    break;
  case ',':
    num_elements++;
    if(curr_num.length() != 0) {
      //i'm not sure this will work but you have to do something similar
      arr1d.push_back((int)curr_num.c_str());
    }
    else {//do some error handling}
  case '0':
  //....
  case '9':
    curr_num += buf[i];
  break;
  default:
  //throw error;
  //there might be other checks you may feel like doing 
  //you'll get better idea as you start writing on your own.
}
i++;
}
if(lparen || rparen)
  //throw error ...
 //...
return 0;
}
```